# eclipse keep on opening the debug configuration window

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, ide

usually when I debug java by pressing on the bug icon, it starts debugging right away and goes to the debug perspective...

but now everytime I click on the bug icon, it always opens up the debug configuration window rather than actually debugging....

any idea as to how to make it debug right away once again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually happens if you have configured Eclipse to "Always launch the previously launched application" (Preferences>Run/Debug>Launching) but Eclipse can't find a previously launched application. Does this happen again if you configured the debug configuration once, debugged successfully with this configuration and then try to rerun it?

Or you could change this setting so Eclipse always tries to run/debug the currently opend file, then it will behave like Ed described it.

Answer (score 0):

If it has a saved configuration for the currently active file in the editor, it will automatically use it.  Otherwise, it will want you to tell it what you want.  I'd suggest getting in the habit of using saved configurations (down-arrow on the debug button) that you've set up.

Answer (score 0):

You could install '[Eclipse Runner](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-runner)' via marketplace. It's a nice addition of run/debug feature.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. I defined the debug configuration and run my Junit but my eclipse was crashing again and again.

I restarted my eclipse and my debugAs menu is back to two options [Debug on server or debug as Junit].

Hope it might help.